# Update an existing column with databricks sql

Tags: sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

My aim is to have a column named `id` replaced with the values from row_number. My SQL statement in an Azure Databricks is:

```
UPDATE x.y
SET id = new_id
WHERE (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY id) AS new_id
      FROM x.y
      )
```

And the traceback I receive:

```
AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name....
```

I've followed the suggestions in the traceback but to no avail. Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

WHERE is used for filtering the rows to update, it doesn't generate rows like that.

Perhaps you want a WITH clause (i.e. a CTE)?

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY id) AS new_id
    FROM x.y
)
UPDATE x.y
SET id = (select new_id from t where t.id = x.y.id)
```

I don't have databricks to try it, but this is how to arrange the query

Answer (score 0):

Currently Databricks SQL doesn't seem to support CTEs with the update statements that require a join, you'll need to use a `MERGE` instead. For example:

```sql
WITH new_ids AS (
 SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY id) AS new_id
 FROM x.y
)
MERGE INTO x.y AS a USING new_ids AS b
ON a.id = b.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET id = b.new_id;
```